# method createToken in class Stripe cannot be applied to given types;stripe.createToken(

Tags: stripe-payments

Stripe error find in android studio can any one help me this is the gradle error
error:

> method createToken in class Stripe cannot be applied to given
> types;
> stripe.createToken(
> ^   required: TokenParams,String,String,ApiResultCallback<? super Token>   found:
> Card,<anonymous ApiResultCallback>   reason: actual and formal
> argument lists differ in length

[image: strip error code]

Comment: What version of the stripe-android library are you using?

Comment: implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-java:5.36.0'

Comment: That's the stripe-java version, what about stripe-android? (https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android)